# Removing Replication on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

I have replication set up between 2 SQL Server 2008 servers, but I would like to reconfigure it again. Is it safe for me to remove replication during normal activity or should I wait until a low traffic time?

The replication is set up between 2 web servers on the same local network and the replicated DB is about 4.5 GB. It is very critical for the data to be online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggestion supplying more information.  How much data is there to replicate, what bandwidth is available for replication (LAN vs WAN), how critical it is for the data to be online.

We've had issues in the past where replication locked certain tables, and because it was between a production server and a web server in a DMZ it took awhile to replicate our large database.  For that reason I'm glad we tested replication during off hours, and we only configure it to run during off hours.

Comment: I added more information